# Unity throws FMod Error Loading File in Builds

Tags: unity-game-engine, fmod

I'm making a Unity game and in the Editor all audio clips play fine.  However, when I try to play them from builds I get this error:

> Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for clip "Variation 1 Master" (FMOD error: Error loading file. )

I've tried loading them in via Resources.Load() instead, and while that works for some of my clips, others continue to throw the same error when I call Resources.Load().  I haven't been able to find anyone else who has seen this issue.

The only thing I can think of is that the size of my project is massive and that is causing problems.  My Assets directory is almost 55GB and the build is almost 10GB.  Almost all of this is Unity-transcoded videos (which load fine).

Does anyone have any ideas for something I haven't thought of?  Thanks!!!